# need to pass multiple sql query at a time in spark sql

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

For the output below , I want to run multiple sql queries something like shown in the code below, but spark does not support multiple sql statement, can you please suggest some other work around for this, it would be really helpful, Thanks :)

```
expected Output:-

Col_name    Max_val Min_value
Name          Null      Null
Age             15        5
height         100        8

CODE :-



  from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df = sc.parallelize([ \
    Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80), \
    Row(name='Kate', age=10, height=90), \
    Row(name='Brain', age=15, height=100)]).toDF()

df.createOrReplaceTempView("Test")

df3 = spark.sql("select max(name) as name ,max(age) as age,max(height) as height from Test" )
df4=df.selectExpr("stack(3,'name',bigint(name),'age',bigint(age),'height',bigint(height)) as (col_name,max_data)")
df5 = spark.sql("select min(name) as name ,min(age) as age,min(height) as height from Test" )
df6=df.selectExpr("stack(3,'name',bigint(name),'age',bigint(age),'height',bigint(height)) as (col_name,min_data)")
df7=df4.join(df6,['col_name'],'inner').groupBy("col_name").orderBy("col_name")
df7.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the exact same structure of the resulting query, you can simply have multiple aggregations in the same step (which would also be more efficient):

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df = sc.parallelize([ \
    Row(name='Alice', age=5, height=80), \
    Row(name='Kate', age=10, height=90), \
    Row(name='Brain', age=15, height=100)]).toDF()
df2 = df.agg(
    F.max(F.col("height")).alias("max_height"),
    F.max(F.col("age")).alias("max_age"),
    F.min(F.col("height")).alias("min_height"),
    F.min(F.col("age")).alias("min_age")
)
df2.collect()
```

This gives a result of: `[Row(max_height=100, max_age=15, min_height=80, min_age=5)]`

To get this in the format above, you would have to use explode.

Answer (score 0):

In scala you can achieve this via Futures API. Then you could expose your Scala
Something like this:

```
for(q <- queries) {
  Future {
    spark.sql(q)
  }
}.map(Await.result(_, Duration("+Inf"))
```

Note that "+Inf" is just illustrative, dont use Inf because timeout will never happen and your code might hang forever.

This will of course not support .show() since that would be ran on top of a DataFrame and here I assume queries are a collection of queries.

You could then wrap this in a spark.ml.Transformer and pass list of queries as Params.

Then you could pass your jar to pyspark at spark submit.

Lastly you could acces then your transformer via spark._jvm.

It is quite a work around and I am only proposing it since I am aware this could work.

Could I ask why is it essential that statements in your example are ran in parallel ? That could help in finding a better suggestion.